# C++: array for loop printing addresses instead of values

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, memory-address

this was an example given to us in class. Could someone explain to me why this prints 29 addresses instead of 29 "0" (zeroes) ?

`int num[29];` is an array which has set aside 29 addresses for 29 integers -i get that part, but in the for loop you arent u printing the values IN those addreses rather than the addresses themselves?

also, whats the difference between `(num+i)` and `(num[]+i)`?

I'm a little confused..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int  num[29];
    for (int i=0;i<29;i++)
        cout << (num+i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason for printing addresses is that

```
(num+i)
```

Is the address of the `i`th element of the array, not the `i`th element itself.  If you want to get the `i`th element, you can write

```
*(num + i)
```

Or, even better:

```
num[i]
```

As for your second question - the syntax `(num + i)` means "the address `i` objects past the start of `num`, and the syntax `(num[] + i)` is not legal C or C++.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

A declaration such as:

```
int num[29];
```

defines a contiguous array of 29 integers.

To access elements of the array use `num[i]` where i is the index (starting at 0 for the 1st element).

The expression `num` on its own gives a pointer (memory address and type) of the first element of the array.

The expression `ptr + i` (where ptr is a pointer and i is an integer) evaluates to a pointer that is i positions (in units of the type of pointer) after ptr.

So `num + i` gives a pointer to the element with index i.

The expression `&a` gives a pointer to some object `a`.

The expression `*ptr` gives the object that some pointer ptr is pointing at.

So the expressions `a` and `*(&a)` are equivalent.

So `num[5]` is the same as `*(num+5)`

and `num+5` is the same as `&num[5]`

and `num` is the same as `&num[0]`

When you print a pointer with cout it will show its address.

When you print an object it will print the value of the object.

So

```
cout << num + 5;
```

will print the address of the 5th (zero-indexed) element of num

and

```
cout << num[5];
```

will print the value of the 5th (zero-indexed) element of num